# Commutative multiplication by matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to solve this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kS4o.png) for couple of hours, please help.

> Let $A,B,C$ be real square matrices of the same order, and suppose $A$ is invertible.
>
> Prove that $(A-B)C=BA^{-1} \implies C(A-B)=A^{-1}B$.

Comment: Please be more specific and complete in the question.

Comment: This site is not an ATM (automated telling machine - pun intended). You might want to at least make an effort to provide context and perhaps type your answer.

Comment: From what I can tell your proposition is not true.  Disprove it with a counterexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first show that $(A-B)C=BA^{-1}$ implies that $A-B$ is invertible. Assume that $A-B$ was not invertible. Then there would be a row vector $v^T\neq 0$ with $v^T(A-B)=0$. This can be written as $v^T A=v^T B$ or as $v^T = v^TBA^{-1}$. 
$$(A-B)C=BA^{-1} \Rightarrow
v^T(A-B)C=v^T BA^{-1} \Rightarrow
0=v^T
$$
This is a contradiction, which means that $A-B$ must be invertible.

We have
$$
(A-B)C(A-B)=BA^{-1}(A-B)=B-BA^{-1}B=(A-B)A^{-1}B
$$
As $A-B$ is invertible, we can multiply this from the left with $(A-B)^{-1}$ and we get
$$
C(A-B)=A^{-1}B
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $C = I$ of the order of $A$ and $B$. Then

$(A-B)I = (A-B) = BA^{-1} $

and also

$I(A-B) = (A-B) = A^{-1}B $

so

$BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$

If your proposition is true then the above line is true. Can you find an example when it isn't?

Comment: why would you assume that C = I?

Comment: The way your problem statement is laid out I can choose any $C$ and the proposition will be true. If I can find a single $C$ where it isn't then the proposition is false. My strategy is therefore to find a $C$ where the proposition doesn't hold. Try it with $C=I$.

Comment: It is not enough to show that there are $A$ and $B$ with $BA^{-1}\neq A^{-1}B$ to create a counterexample, because it is not obvious that there are matrices $A$ and $B$ such that I can choose $C=I$ and still $(A-B)C=BA^{-1}$ holds.